# Android : Fill yellow color proportional to on Touch over the image

Tags: android, gesture

[image]

I have a dial-or image as shown in which whenever i move the finger in clockwise manner the part covered of sub ring gets yellow in color.I tried to apply this scenario through gesture overlay but do not serve the requirement.

Any idea is welcomed.Please assist me and thanks in advance.